# Difference between riechen an und riechen nach

Tags: verb, vocabulary

Wann kann man  "riechen an" oder "riechen nach" benutzen ?

Comment: Questions about differences in meaning should show reserach effort (see http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-do-i-ask-good-on-topic-questions-for-translations-or-about-differences). What did your dictionaries say? Why did you not find your answer there?

Answer (score 8):

#### riechen an

> Das Mädchen riecht an der frischen Wäsche. (Der Hund schnuppert an der Einkaufstüte.)

[image]

#### riechen nach

> Die ganze Wohnung riecht (duftet) nach Weihnachtsgebäck.

Answer (score 4):

"Riechen" hat zwei Bedeutungen:

1. Einen Geruch wahrnehmen (ich rieche die Blume).
2. Einen Geruch verströmen (die Blume riecht gut).

"Riechen an" gehört thematisch zur ersten Bedeutung: Es bedeutet, dass man mit der Nase an etwas heran geht, um den Geruch besser wahrzunehmen.

Eine stark duftende Blume kann ich auch aus der Entfernung riechen. Um an der Blume zu riechen, muss ich hingegen nahe herangehen. Umgekehrt kann ich an einer Plastikblume riechen, auch wenn ich dabei wahrscheinlich nichts riechen werde.

"Riechen nach" hingegen gehört zur zweiten Bedeutung. Es bedeutet, dass der verströmte Geruch einem anderen Geruch ähnelt.

Es gibt zum Beispiel eine fleischfressende Pflanze, die nach verwesendem Fleisch riecht, um Fliegen anzulocken. Das heißt, der Geruch der Pflanze ähnelt dem Geruch von verwesendem Fleisch.

Vergleiche auch die alte Scherzfrage (zur Auflösung den Mauszeiger über das freie Feld unter der Frage fahren):

> –Wie hält man ein Stinktier vom Riechen ab?
>   –Indem man ihm die Nase zuhält!

Answer (score 1):

**riechen an (etwas/jemandem)**

> Der Geruch ist an eine bestimmte Sache oder Person geknüpft

**riechen nach**

> Der Geruch wird indirekt wahrgenommen und umgibt einen